# Android: Check if device is capable of 3 or more touches

Tags: java, android, multi-touch, gestures

I know there is a way to check if a device is capable of multi-touch. However these seems to return `true` if a device is capable of 2 or more touches.

I need to know if the device is capable of 3 touches. Exactly 3 touches, or 3 or more touches, either check is acceptable. Anyhow know how to do this?

I am okay with either a `boolean` that says 3 or more are supported or simply return an number for the number of touches available.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check for support for three touches.

You can use `PackageManager` and `hasSystemFeature()` to check for hardware features. However, the only hardware features related to multitouch are either two touches (`android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch` or `android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct`) or five touches (`android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.jazzhand`), not three, four, six, seven, eight, pi, *e*, or Avogadro's number of touches.

That being said, I would expect that most devices supporting three touches would support five and qualify for `jazzhand`.